# Hashing algorithms for data summary

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am on the search for a non-cryptographic hashing algorithm with a given set of properties, but I do not know how to describe it in Google-able terms.

Problem space: I have a vector of 64-bit integers which are *mostly* linearlly distributed throughout that space. There are two exceptions to this rule: (1) The number `0` occurs considerably frequently and (2) if a number *x* occurs, it is more likely to occur again than 2^-64. The goal is, given two vectors **A** and **B**, to have a convenient mechanism for quickly detecting if **A** and **B** are not the same. Not all vectors are of fixed size, but any vector I wish to compare to another will have the same size (aka: a size check is trivial).

The only special requirement I have is I would like the ability to "back out" a piece of data. In other words, given **A**[i] = x and a hash(**A**), it should be cheap to compute hash(**A**) for **A**[i] = y. In other words, I want a non-cryptographic hash.

---

The most reasonable thing I have come up with is this (in Python-ish):

```
# Imagine this uses a Mersenne Twister or some other seeded RNG...
NUMS = generate_numbers(seed)

def hash(a):
    out = 0
    for idx in range(len(a)):
        out ^= a[idx] ^ NUMS[idx]
    return out

def hash_replace(orig_hash, idx, orig_val, new_val):
    return orig_hash ^ (orig_val ^ NUMS[idx]) ^ (new_val ^ NUMS[idx])
```

It is an exceedingly simple algorithm and it probably works okay. However, all my experience with writing hashing algorithms tells me somebody else has already solved this problem in a better way.

Comment: Why don't you simply use something simple like md5 and compare the two arrays value by value if the two hash are equals? To improve it a bit, you can append the size to the md5 digest, to further reduce the number of collisions. Because of the pigeonhole principle, you cannot avoid collisions at all, so I'd maybe concentrate on finding a fast hash algorithm, instead of a complex one that gives me few advantages.

Comment: @skypjack You are missing his requirement for a fast update of the hash vaue if only a single field of the vector changes.

Comment: Indeed it's why I suggested to concentrate on a fast hashing algorithm, instead of one that fits well with the data distribution. Anyway, you are right saying that the example of the extended md5 is trivial and it is not a viable solution (for it requires to compute a new value as a whole).

Comment: @skypjack: Zotta is right, so I'll clarify the why a bit more. MD5 is very fast, but extremely slow compared to backing out a single element and inserting one (per the scheme provided in my question). My vectors are large enough and updated frequently enough for the difference to matter.

Comment: See the response below. I guess the family of algorithms you are referring to is that one, but I've never used them for hashing purposes, so that's all what I can do, I'm sorry. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called `homomorphic hashing algorithm` and it has already been discussed [Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem).

As far as I can see from that discussion, there are no practical implementation nowadays.

The most interesting feature, the one for which I guess it fits your needs, is that:

```
H(x*y) = H(x)*H(y)
```

Because of that, you can freely define the lower limit of your unit and rely on that property.

I've used the [Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) a few years ago (there was a Java implementation somewhere, but I don't have anymore the link) during my studies, but it's far more complex in respect of what you are looking for.

It has interesting feature under certain constraints, like the following one:

```
n*C(x) = C(n*x)
```

Again, it looks to me similar to what you are looking for, so maybe you should search for this family of hashing algorithms. I'll have a try with Google searching for a more specific link.

References:

[This one](http://blog.notdot.net/2012/08/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Homomorphic-Hashing) is quite interesting, but maybe it is not a viable solution because of your space that is [0-2^64[ (unless you accept to deal with big numbers).